# Unexpected parameter(s) after input APK (--out): Can't sign the apk for prod build

Tags: android, apk, build-tools, apksigner

I am trying to do a production build of an apk but when I try to sign it with the following command:

`apksigner.bat sign --ks app-release-key.jks --out app-release-unsigned.apk app-release-unsigned-aligned.apk`

I get the below error:

`Unexpected parameter(s) after input APK (--out)`

I am following [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline) to sign the app manually from the command line.

I'm using the apksigner .bat file located at `../Android/Sdk/build-tools/32.0.0` and as you can see I'm using Android build tools 32.0.0. I've tried different things

1. Using jarsigner to sign the app, and although it successfully signed the app, my app would not load when I installed it onto the device. Also, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file) we should use apksigner if we're using build-tools 24.0.3 and older.
2. Tried to use this as well
   `apksigner.bat sign --ks test.jks --ks-key-alias test --ks-pass pass:testtest --key-pass pass:testtest Test_Aligned.apk` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653492/apksigner-not-accepting-password) but it gave me the error `Unexpected parameter(s) after input APK (--ks-key-alias)`
3. Tried using the jar apksigner located at `../Android/Sdk/build-tools/32.0.0/bin` but I'm receiving the same error.

Any suggestions would help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve this?